# Provisioning API for Google Groups to Add a Member

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-apps, google-provisioning-api

Okay, I've signed up for Google Apps Business, I've enabled provisioning in the settings. I've created a group named 'test'.  I've added my e-mail as owner of the group 'myEmail@gmail.com' as well as my 'admin@myTestDomain.mygbiz.com'.

Here is my code in Python, using Aptana studio :

```
import gdata.apps.groups.client

groupClient = gdata.apps.groups.client.GroupsProvisioningClient(domain='myTestDomain.mygbiz.com')
groupClient.ClientLogin(email='admin@myTestDomain.mygbiz.com', password='myPassword', source='apps')
groupClient.AddMemberToGroup('test', 'emailToAdd@gmail.com')
```

I've tried to do this in many different ways with no success. Anyone have some ideas? Your help would be appreciated.

Screenshots: [image: Google settings]
[image: Google settings]
[image: my code in Aptana]

**edit 1**: I should note that I've also used my actual e-mail on mygbiz domain as owner of the group with no success.

**edit 2**: I have also enabled my google groups as 'public' in my settings and have allowed owners to add members from outside of the domain.

Comment: Is the email that you're logging in with an admin account for your domain or is it actually a consumer Gmail account?

Comment: @William, I've tried both. I'll update the code on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake.  I forgot to include gdata in my 'site-packages' folder.  It works now.